# Problems importing file from Support to be used in Integration test case

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress

Cypress won't allow me to import my page object file into my test case. The file is constructed correctly but when I try to import FROM the 'support' folder in to my test case the 'support folder'  doesn't appear.  [Please watch this video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n1np6oopcxi67b8/Can%27t%20import%20folder.mp4?dl=0), it clearly shows what I am experiencing.

Here is the code:

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />
 
import Homepage from '../'
 
describe('My test feature',function() {
 
    beforeEach(function(){
       cy.fixture('example').then(function(data){ 
 
             this.data=data 
 
            })
 
    })
 
    
 
    it('my first test scenario', function(){
   
        cy.visit('https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/')
        cy.get('input[name="name"]:nth-child(2)').type(this.data.name)
        cy.get('select').select(this.data.gender)
 
        cy.get('input[name="name"]:nth-child(1)').should('have.value',this.data.name )  
        cy.get('input[name="name"]:nth-child(2)').should('have.attr', 'minlength','2')
        cy.get('input[id=inlineRadio3]').should('be.disabled')
 
        cy.get('a[href="/angularpractice/shop"]').click()
        
 
        this.data.mobileHandset.forEach(function(element) {
 
              cy.AddToCart(element)  
            });
 
   
     })//end of test case 
   
 
 
 
   })//end of describe
```

The Page object file in the 'support' folder

```
 class Homepage
{
 
    getCustomerRegistrationName()
    {
        return cy.get('input[name="name"]:nth-child(2)')
    }
   
     getTwoWayDataBinding()
     {
         return cy.get('input[name="name"]:nth-child(1)')
     }
 
     getGenderDropdownList()
     {
         return cy.get('select')
     }
 
    getEntrepreneur()
    {
        return cy.get('#inlineRadio3')
    }
 
    getShopTab()
    {
        return cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .nav-link')
    }
 
}
 
export default Homepage;
```

Answer (score 2):

If your spec file is in `cypress/integration/` and your POM class in `cypress/support/pageObjects/`, then you need to import your POM class like this:

```js
import Homepage from '../support/pageObjects/Homepage';
```

because you need to go one level up and then into `support/pageObjects/` directory.

Comment: @pavelsman thanks for the response. I just tried your suggestion.  I posted a video in the question to show you what happened.

Comment: @fypnlp: Isn't your spec file in `cypress/integration/examples/` directory? If so, you need to go one more level up: `'../../support/pageObjects/Homepage'`

Comment: Yes my spec file is in cypress/integration/examples/.  let me try and I will let you know what happens

Comment: @pavelsman I updated the click here video link with the outcome from you suggestion.

Comment: @fypnlp: But when you run your test case, does it actually work (that is can you use the imported `Homepage` class)? It might be only some settings of your IDE.

Comment: @pavelsman sorry for the late reply.  Let me check. I will get back  to you. I really want to get this resolved because it I want this to help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,  so I figured out what the problem is. Case sensitivity in cypress is KEY!!! I think that I wasn't writing the file I wanted to import with the correct letter casing as it's displayed in the framework.  It's these small things that can cost you time to trouble shoot as they're so tricky to see.

Also, as a side not make sure you 'save all'  all the time as sometimes things won't work as expected because the entire framework hasn't been saved - only the file you are working in (if that makes sense).

[image]